# Insert text into UITextView programmatically without moving caret position.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

So I have a UITextView that the user can edit, but there may also be some text inserted programmatically into the textView as well, and it could be inserted at any arbitrary range in the textView. Currently, this also moves the caret position from where the user was currently working, which is undesirable. So anytime I do this:

```
self.textView.text = //some text inserted
```

It moves the caret position. So what would be the best way to prevent the caret position from moving, or make it **totally ignorant and independent** of programmatic changes and only move in response to user changes?

Answer (score 1):

The best answer would be to set the text that is inserted like you have, but then after, set the caret position using the following method:

`textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0,0)`

The first number is the spot in the text view you would like to put the caret. If you would like to keep it at the beginning regardless of whatever text is added, this is how you would do it. You would, however, want to include a conditional to keep this only around the non-typed text being added. When the user is typing, you want the caret to move.

Answer (score 0):

Before you programatically insert your text, you can get the current insertion point via [UITextView's "`selectedRange`" property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/selectedRange).

Once you're done inserting the new text, you can reset the text view's selected range to what it was prior to insertion... or, if the insertion point was before the new block of text inserted, you'll need to recalculate the position of the previous caret location taking into account the length of the inserted text.

Comment: So this is what I thought would work also, and I thought of it before asking the question, but I cannot get it to work correctly for my use case. I am either missing something, or I need something more. Though I have been working on this for a bit, so my brain is fried at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're supposed to use the [`UITextView`'s `textStorage` property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618611-textstorage).

For example:

```
let string = "some text"
let range = NSRange(location: 4, length: 0) // arbitrary range
textView.textStorage.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: string)
```

Doing it this way doesn't cause the cursor to move.

Note: If you initialize a `UITextView` the typical way—for example, in code it's just `UITextView(frame: .zero, textContainer: nil)`—then `textStorage` gets set to an instance of [`NSConcreteTextStorage`](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/NSConcreteTextStorage.h), which is a subclass of [`NSTextStorage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nstextstorage), which is a subclass of [`NSMutableAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableattributedstring).